# Smoke Transforming with Bounding Box

Tags: smoke-simulation

I add an object, then add the Quick Effects Smoke to that object. The problem comes when I try to change the bounding box for the field of smoke. Any transform I do the the bounding box, gets transferred to my smoke (without the original object changing. Nothing I do seams to correct this and I can't seem to find anything to turn this off. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I am running 2.82.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.